# Need to find out which button was pressed

Tags: instance, godot, godot4

The following scripts job is to scan the given directory and find out how many files(or characters) are in it. Then it creates a number of buttons equal to the total number of files. Currently my problem is that i have no way knowing which button is pressed during run time.

```
extends Control

#number of characters to be imported
var characters = 0
#file names of all avalible chararters
var files = []
#buttons associated with said characters
var array = []

# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    scan_directory()
    populate()
    setup()

#scans for the number of characters in the folder
func scan_directory():
    var current = ""
    var dir = DirAccess.open("res://Characters/")
    dir.list_dir_begin()
    current = dir.get_next()
    while current != "":
        files.push_back(current)
        current = dir.get_next()
    print(files)
    characters = files.size()

func setup():
    var x = 0
    for i in characters:
        var but = array[x]
        var path = "res://Characters/" + files[x] + "/"+ files[x] + ".gd"
       var char = load(path)
       var dic = char.import()
       x += 1

#creates buttons equal to the number of characters
func populate():
    var x = 100
    var y = 100
    var texture = Texture2D.new()
    texture = load("res://img/button.jpg")

    for i in characters:
        var but = Button.new()
        var path = load("res://Scripts/Character_Select.gd")
        add_child(but)
        but.pressed.connect(self.export)
        but.set_position(Vector2(x,y))
        but.set_button_icon(texture)
        x += 250
        if x > 1250:
            x = 100
            y += 250
        array.push_back(but)
    print(array)

func export():
    var temp = self.get_instance_id()
    print("Current id: " + str(temp))
```

So im currently looking for a way to either have the button pass a varible when clicked or be able to know the instance id of the button that was clicked so i can compare it to know buttons in the array.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you connect to the signal:

```
but.pressed.connect(self.export)
```

What you are passing is a `Callable` created from the method `export`. You can `bind` arguments to it, like this:

```
but.pressed.connect(self.export.bind(1))
```

Then when the signal is emitted, it will pass that as argument to the method `export`. You, of course, need a parameter to receive it, for example:

```
func export(data):
    prints(data)
    # ...
```

---

In your case, you probably want to pass the iterator variable. This is the idea:

```
for i in blahblahblah:
    # ...
    # stuff
    # ...
    but.pressed.connect(self.export.bind(i))
    # ...
    # other stuff
    # ...
```

Since each time it would be binding a different value, this allows you know which one it is.

Of course, you can bind something else if you prefer.